# Heat-pump style AC is not putting out cool air

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, heat-pump

I live in the Northern area of the US, and I have a heat-pump style AC unit. So there is an AC unit with big fan outside my house, and there is a furnace in my attic. I bought this house 10 years ago brand new and came with this setup.

So lately the AC is not putting out cool air and requested HVAC export to do a refrigerant refill. The HVAC guy told me that he increased the refrigerant level from 55 lb to 75 lbs. He also mentions 70 lbs were recommended by the manufacture.

An hour after the refrigerant refill, I still don't feel any cold air coming out from my ceiling vents, it's just normal fan air. Also, I have replaced all my home air filters already.

What should I do next? The label for my AC Unit is as below:

[image]

Comment: I realize it's a bit late, but it may have been worthwhile to have the tech do a diagnostic on the system to ensure that low coolant was the _only_ problem. Was 70lbs the recommended amount or just the top of the recommended range? Was the existing 55lbs within the acceptable range?

Comment: I really have no idea with the manufacture ranges. The HVAC guy is gone.

Comment: I understand (though it you post the make & model, I'm sure someone will be able to look it up). These were thoughts for the future. <-- that wasn't all that clear.

Comment: I'm surprised the tech just filled the system and didn't ask any other questions or do any other diagnosis.  Sounds like he needs to come back and do a proper service call.

Comment: Guys, I went outside and took a picture of that unit label, and updated my original post. Is this unit here: https://www.lennoxpros.com/13hpd-024-230-heat-pump2ton230-1/p/94M46

Comment: Call the better business bureau after reading my answer 70 psi means absolutely nothing! Look up the temp pressure charts for r22 online you will see it is temperature dependent and there will be a low side pressure and a high side pressure , look at your system tag . Can’t say much more.

Answer (score 0):

Your guy knew nothing! Or is trying to take advantage of you! 
 A full recharge of your system would take 6 lbs 3 oz of r22.  This is an obsolete refrigerant, yes it can still be purchased. But is expensive you do not fill by pressure alone! A few oz of r22 can provide much more than 70psi , to properly charge a system super heat and sub cooling is used these are the pressures and temps on the low and high sides or suction and high pressure lines of the system while measuring temps. At both locations 70 psi is meaningless by itself. 
Contact a reputable hvac company , they may try to sell you a new system but 3 lbs may also provide a full charge and give you another 5,6,7 years who knows but it is a small system and may be worth a recharge.

Comment: Yeah, the guy keeps saying my AC unit is too old to work with. Also, charge $350. Which online max quote was at $250.

Comment: 10 lbs of r22 on line today 160.00 . I would call someone else this guy has no idea what he is talking about. You have a quality unit I replaced a compressor in a r22 system last month It did not leak and I was able to recover 10 lbs of a 12 lb system ,Pressure tested good  , pulled a vacuum recharged with the recovered Freon and added 2 lbs it is working great and with the new compressor I expect that system to run for at least 10 years. Not bad for a 5 ton system my cost under 500$ to repair. Charging 100 over quote and did not fix BBB time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I'll already contact another company. I'll update you after the service.